# Comparison of nested properties

Tags: java, apache-commons, object-comparison

Let's say I have two objects with property Customer which is object that has property ID. How would you compare those two object. 
I tried to write some common java if statement, but is long and really clumsy.

I tried something like this

```
new EqualsBuilder().append(o1.getCustomer(), o2.getCustomer())
            .append(o1.getCustomer().getId(), o2.getCustomer().getId()).isEquals()
```

but it fails if getCustomer of one object returns null(this is for cases the object is for anonymous customer, thus NullPointerException occurs). How can I write it in the most readable way. Can I somehow utilize java Optional??

UPDATE:
Problem is I'm comparing uncomparable. O1 and o2 are different classes. In this case the primal flaw is that I cannot use EqualsBuilder at all.

Maybe I can use this, which is really not more readable then if statement.

```
Object1 o1 = ...;
Object2 o2 = ...;
boolean equals Optional.of(o1).map(VoucherDTO::getCustomer).map(CustomerDTO::getId).orElse(0L).equals(Optional.of(o1).map(VoucherDTO::getCustomer).map(CustomerDTO::getId).orElse(0L));
```

Comment: Your code tests if the two customers are equal, and if their IDs are equal. The second check looks redundant to me: if two customers are equal, shouldn't their ID be equal, too? Pots the relevant code (i.e. the Customer class).

Comment: In our case no, because the customer property can be null to signalize the user is anonymous.

Comment: Maybe `new EqualsBuilder().append(Optional.of(o1).map(Card::getCustomer).map(CustomerDTO::getId).orElse(0L), Optional.of(o2).map(Card::getCustomer).map(CustomerDTO::getId).orElse(0L)).isEquals()`

Comment: If the customer property is null because it is anonymous, then it is not equal to another customer that is not anonymous. So the first part already catches that (`append(o1.getCustomer(), o2.getCustomer())`), you don't need the second part `append(o1.getCustomer().getId(), o2.getCustomer().getId())`

Answer (score 2):

How about the following?  I would makes it that the two customers are only equal if the ids are equal.

```
return o1.getCustomer() == null 
       ? o2.getCustomer() == null
       : o1.getCustomer().equals(o2.getCustomer())
                  &&  o1.getCustomer().getId() == o2.getCustomer().getId();
```

Comment: The problem is that the o1.getCustomer() can be null

Comment: @Zveratko if both are null, do you want them to be equal?

Comment: @Zveratko That will only cause a problem if `o2.getCustomer()` is also `null`, but if it is, the above code will throw a NullPointerException.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I have edited it to allow them to both be `null`.